# child.bat not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: cmd, batch-processing

I have been going through a bat file issue.

I'm calling one bat file in main bat file. The two bat files are in same folder i.e. "D:\"

Test.bat:

```
SET str=HELLO
ECHO say %str% Test
Call Child.bat
```

Child.bat:

```
ECHO say %str% child
```

In `Test.bat` file I have declared a variable `str` and using it in child bat file also. When I'm running Test.bat directly by double clicking it is working as expected and I will get result

```
say HELLO Test
say HELLO Child
```

But the problem is here, if i'm running the Test.bat file from another machine in command prompt as

- Open run
- enter //Server/D$/Test.bat

it is executing only Test.bat and fails to invoke Child.bat as I get output like

```
say HELLO Test
Child.bat not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

and on the above of command prompt I can see one statement like

```
'\\Server\D$\' CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

Actually I need to set up a sql job to invoke the Test.bat file.

How do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*test.bat*

```
pushd "%~dp0"
SET str=HELLO
ECHO say %str% Test
Call Child.bat
popd
```

Just create a temporary mapping and change the current folder to it. At the end release it. `pushd /popd` will handle it.

BUT while it will work, if when the batch file is called the current active directory is a UNC path (what happens when calling it from the windows `run` dialog), the UNC error will be shown. If you want to avoid it, ensure that the process is launched with a different directory as default.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution. But adding the pushh and popd din't solve the issue, i'm not sure why. I have replaced 'Child.bat' with '%~dp0\Child.bat' in test.bat file then it started working.

Comment: @Rajuvadnala, sorry, typo error (now changed) it should be `pushd`